# Error in 'System_path_to_tesseract.exe'. Tesseract not found error in linux

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use pytesseract library on linux but receiving the following error.
How to solve this error log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rawnewton/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 254, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1842, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'System_path_to_tesseract.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/2E50C9C750C995CD/Projects/Public/MajorProject/image_text.py", line 58, in <module>
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped)
  File "/home/rawnewton/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 416, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "/home/rawnewton/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 419, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "/home/rawnewton/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 286, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/home/rawnewton/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 258, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: System_path_to_tesseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

I have installed it using the following commands:

```
pip install tesseract
pip install tesseract-ocr
```

I am using Xubuntu version 20.04.

Comment: Hello and welcome ! Can you please share the code you wrote to use the lib ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: pip install pytesseract and here is link for tessarct-ocr https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract